# How can we monitor audio of subject using headphone while recording video using iphone or samsung galaxy s4?

Tags: video-recording, audio-recording

How can we monitor audio of subject using headphone while recording video using iphone or samsung galaxy s4?

I want to monitor audio while recording video using smartphone

Answer (score 1):

You could use an [adapter](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/bnh/controller/home?O=&sku=765531&gclid=CjwKEAjwuoOpBRCSy6yQm66J1g8SJABrXW481DvXRpCNNzYNEDvuQmE7jkfKqaEc7wMJji9HRVbVoBoCVrjw_wcB&Q=&is=REG&A=details) to split the cell phone jack into XLR & 3.5mm.  Then just plug in your XLR mic and headphones.

Or you could record [double-system audio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-system_recording).  Get a second, purpose-built audio recording device like a [Zoom](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/699403-REG/Zoom_H1_H1_Ultra_Portable_Digital_Audio.html), and monitor that while you shoot with your cell phone.  It's super easy to match up the audio again in most editing software nowadays.